# Dim a LED array through PWM on power supply or output enable?

Tags: led, pwm, led-strip, shift-register, led-matrix

I have an 8-LED array driven by an 8-channel source driver ([TD62783AP](http://acg.media.mit.edu/people/simong/hotpants/tech/media/TD62783AF.pdf)) controlled from an 8-bit shift register ([74HC4094](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4094.pdf)).

When it comes to dimming the LEDs using PWM, I came up with two solutions, and I was wondering if one was better than the other:

- I can PWM the Output Enable pin of the shift register
- I can PWM the supply VCC of the source driver

Which one, if any, would be best, and why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you should apply the PWM signal to the OE pin of the shift register because the driver is not designed to have a voltage level at the inputs higher than the supply voltage due to the clamp diodes at the input.